# JavaEE call page issue on request parameter

Tags: java, url, jakarta-ee, redirect, request

I have belowcode in my POSTmethod of a page.
The problem is that I want to go to the url */news-management#tab_default_1* and forward the request too.

So when I use `getRequestDispatcher()` the request is forwarded but the URLis just ***/news_management***

And when I use `sendRedirect()` the url is good but the request is not forwarded:

```java
String del = request.getParameter("delete");
    Base base = new Base();

    if (request.getParameter("object").length() > 200)
        request.setAttribute("bad", "Object length is too big");
    if (request.getParameter("message").length() > 800)
        request.setAttribute("bad", "Content length is too big");
    if (del != null)
        base.deleteNews(del);
    if (request.getParameter("add") != null)
    {
        Newsletter nl = new Newsletter();
        nl.setObject(request.getParameter("object"));
        nl.setMessage(request.getParameter("message"));
        base.addNews(nl);
    }
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/news-management.jsp").forward(request, response);
    //response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/news-management#tab_default_1");
```

Any idea on how to get the desired behaviour?

Comment: did u try putting the "/WEB-INF/news-management.jsp#tab_default_1"

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work

Comment: this question is discussed here - this is called URL fragmentation --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277978/using-hash-symbol-in-forward-url-with-requestdispatcher

Comment: Ok thank's i will try to find another way solve that